# Emacs Quick View (C-c C-v) fails after upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: emacs, ubuntu, viewers

I upgraded to Ubuntu Linux 11.04 yesterday, and I realize that Quick View (C-c C-v) in Emacs, which opened pdf with okular, does not work anymore. C-c C-v does nothing now; I also try to launch it via menu bar: Command -> Quick View, it shows "menu-bar Command Quick View", that is it.

I could observe that the pdf file is actually generated (by C-c C-c), but oddly it could not be opened from Emacs. Here is the related part of my .emacs:

```lisp
(server-start)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-PDF-mode) 
(defun pdf-with-okular ()
(add-to-list 'TeX-output-view-style
(quote ("^pdf$" "." "okular %o %(outpage)"))))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'pdf-with-okular t)

(custom-set-variables
 '(LaTeX-command "latex -synctex=1")
 '(cua-mode t nil (cua-base))
 '(show-paren-mode t))
```

Could anyone help? Thank you very much

Comment: I would ask this question on our sister site askubuntu.com or in a emacs forum.

Comment: Probably irrelevant - but I've noticed that when Okular updates, I've needed to restart the Emacs server in order to get forward search to work. But presumably you restarted your computer when you updated, so the Emacs server would have been restarted.

Comment: Hopefully more helpful: after something updated (emacs, auctex, ubuntu, okular, I'm not sure which), I found that I needed to add okular-search.el to get it to work (see the code here: https://inthearmchair.wordpress.com/2010/11/15/latex-forward-pdf-search-with-emacs/ )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do <kbd>M-x</kbd> and then type `customize-variable`. And then press enter. Then type `TeX-view-program-selection` and make sure it is set to okular. I don't use okular, so I'm not sure I can be of much more use if that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Indeed, it is related to `TeX-view-program-selection`. I have added these 2 lines in my .emacs file:

Comment: `(setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Okular" "okular --unique %u")))`
`(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Okular") (output-dvi "Okular")))`

Comment: However, it does not solve the problem totally. Here is a detailed [description](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849416/how-to-set-the-command-of-view-by-default-with-a-real-filename). Hope you could help, thank you.

Comment: The problem is finally solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849416/how-to-set-the-command-of-view-by-default-with-a-real-filename)