# Setup SyncTeX with Emacs on debian stable (squeeze)

Tags: auctex, forward-inverse-search, debian

Is it possible to setup SyncTeX with Emacs on debian stable (squeeze)?

Emacs24 is available from http://emacs.naquadah.org/ but squeeze is at its end of cycle and most other tools are outdated.

```
$ evince --version
GNOME Document Viewer 2.30.3

$ okular --version
Qt: 4.6.3
KDE Development Platform: 4.4.5 (KDE 4.4.5)
Okular: 0.10.5
```

I found the article [Setup SyncTeX with Emacs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29813/setup-synctex-with-emacs) but could not reproduce it here yet and want to know if there is a chance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29813/3406

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SyncTeX has been supported by Evince since version 2.32, while the Evince version on Debian Squeeze is 2.30. So it is not possible to setup SyncTeX with Evince.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why it shouldn't work. In my opinion, you should try it right away and come back here only if you have any trouble during the setting up.

Since you have okular, I would disadvise following the guide you mentioned : it is made for evince, which is known to be way more troublesome than okular for synctex.

With okular, forward search is just a matter of compiling the file with synctex, and setting the viewer to go to the corresponding line.

For this, addind the following lines to your `.emacs` shoud do (taken from [Emacs Quick View (C-c C-v) fails after upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17017/quick-view-c-c-c-v-does-not-work-anymore-after-upgrading-to-11-04) ):

```
(server-start)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-PDF-mode) 
(defun pdf-with-okular ()
(add-to-list 'TeX-output-view-style
(quote ("^pdf$" "." "okular %o %(outpage)"))))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'pdf-with-okular t)

(custom-set-variables
 '(LaTeX-command "latex -synctex=1")
)
```

Reverse search is even easier : all you have to do is, in okular options, set `emacsclient` as default viewer, and, if needed, start emacs server.